# Where the `term` and `policer` would appear?

Tags: juniper, juniper-junos

Where the `term` and `policer` would appear?

In juniper, there have `filter`, `term` and `policer`.

I know the `filter` is under `firewall`, but how about the `term` and `policer`?

how to understand the concept?

I know the `term` can understand an interface, or under a `policy-statement`:

```
set policy-options policy-statement EXPORT-3121 term NO-EBGP-3121 then reject
```

so, how to understand the concept, then we can know where we can put the `term` and `policer`?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both `term` and `policer` can be placed in a multiple sections of the configuration.

**Policers**

Policers are *defined* like this, obviously you can change it to your needs:

```
{master}[edit firewall]
policer TEST_POLICER {
    if-exceeding {
        bandwidth-limit 900m;
        burst-size-limit 128k;
    }
    then discard;
}
```

Policers can be *applied* in multiple areas:

Directly on Interfaces

```
jhead@MX960-re0# show interfaces xe-3/0/0:2
unit 0 {
    family inet {
        policer {
            input TEST_POLICER;
            output TEST_POLICER;
        }
    }
}
```

As a Firewall Filter Action

```
jhead@MX960-re0# show firewall
family inet {
    filter TEST_FILTER {
        term TEST_TERM {
            then policer TEST_POLICER;
        }
    }
}
```

**Terms**

Terms have 2 rules:

1. Terms are **mandatory** when inside of a firewall filter.  With this in mind, if you need to put a policer in a firewall filter, it will always be inside of a term.
2. Terms are **NOT** mandatory when inside of a policy.